# Web scraper not getting data from table (Java) using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup, html-tbody

I am working on a web scraper to gather stats from https://www.nba.com for a project, but my scraper is somehow not gathering data from the table, as the table says it has size 0 (makes it seem like its not getting the table at all).

Could someone let me know if I am doing something wrong and how to fix it?

[image: My NBA scraper code]

[image: The inspect code from NBA.com]

I tried to gather from table tbody.Crom_body__UYOcU and to make sure it worked, I checked the size. Should've been much more than 0 (50 or 100 I do not remember) but returned just 0 from size().

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The inspect tools are not very useful for this use-case as they show the generated HTML after all scripts were run. Jsoup instead just fetches the initial HTML without running any scripts. If you take a look at the context menu > View Source you'll see that the HTML of this page does not contain the statistics eventually shown

Comment: In other words: In a world of JS frameworks and XHR requests good old HTML scraping as JSOUP provides it might simply not provide you with any useful information

Comment: However, if you check the inspect tool's network tab you'll see the content data loaded as JSON from https://stats.nba.com/stats/leagueLeaders?LeagueID=00&PerMode=PerGame&Scope=S&Season=2022-23&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&StatCategory=PTS For a hobby project you could as well fetch it from there

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! I see you haven't yet taken the [tour]. Also, take a look at [ask]. Do not post images of your code but rather [edit] your question and paste it as a formatted code block.